# ¿Como puedo actualizar el contenido de un div con javascript y php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente:
De primera mano me es útil especificarles los lenguajes que estoy usando:

- HTML: Para el esqueleto de mi pagina.
- CSS: Para los estilos.
- JS: Para, en base a mis investigaciones con respecto al tema, quien sea que detone una función para poder actualizar el contenido de mi div, mas adelante ingreso lo que ya he intentado.
- PHP: Para extraer información de mi base de datos.
- MySQL (MariaDB con XAMPP): Para los datos como tal.

Ahora bien, mi plan es que en base a tocar un elemento que figura como categoría, actualice un div en el que esta la información recabada de la base de datos.
Sea la siguiente imagen para que puedan entenderme mejor:

[image: Demostracion para comprender el problema]

En contenido hay algo previamente cargado. Ya con el detonante, se cargará el otro en cuestion.

**¿Qué he intentado?**
En base a mis investigaciones que hecho del tema, el proceso consiste en guardar en un archivo php por aparte la estructura del contenido y como es que lo obtengo de la base de datos.
Dicha estructura esta de la forma:

```
//"cont-princi" es el delimitante de el area de Contenido
<aside id="cont-princi">
//"manifest-page" es un contenedor donde esta un encabezado. 
        <div id="manifest-page">
    //"title-master" es el encabezado como tal
            <div id="title-master">
                <p>Articulos recomendados</p>
            </div>
    //Un boton para cerrar sesion
            <button id="make-quest">Cerrar sesion</button>
        </div>

//Aqui obtenemos la informacion por medio de php, la conexion, consulta y demas esta arriba.
        <?php 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        ?>
//"art" es el contenedor que tiene los elementos de el articulo
            <div class="art">
//La informacion ya como tal
                <p class="titleP"><?php echo $row['titulo']?></p>
                <p class="cuerpoP"><?php echo $row['contenido'] ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
    </aside>
```

Ahora bien, por parte de la categoria, tengo un detonante de una funcion JS, de esta forma:

```
<div class="elemento" onclick="cargaCategoriaTal()">
    <p>Categoria Tal</p>
</div>
```

Y a continuación viene lo que he investigado, en un JS creo la función ya nombrada y se pone un código que aparentemente debe hacer ese reload del div en cuestión, cargando un archivo php. De esta forma:

```
function cargaCategoriaTal(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refrescarid = setInterval(function() {
            $("#cont-princi").load("categoriaTal.php")
            .error(function() { alert("Error"); });
        }, 0); // Tiempo
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });              
    });
}
```

Admire que estamos pasando el id del div "cont-princi" y asi mismo un archivo (Que esta el mismo nivel) php donde se supone que esta el "nuevo" contenido.
En ese "nuevo" php tengo, por decirlo de alguna manera, la misma estructura del apartado de contenido (Lo mismo hare para cada otra categoria), de esta forma:

//Note como mantenemos los mismos nombres de id para que "convergan" con los estilos

```
<aside id="cont-princi">
        <div id="manifest-page">
            <div id="title-master">
                <p>Categoria 2</p>
            </div>
            <button id="make-quest">Cerrar Sesion</button>
            //Aca adentro ira lo similar que en el anterior. con algo especial de la categoria, 
//va el correspondiente codigo php
        </div>
</aside>
```

El detalle es que no funciona, detono ese metodo y no responde, no hace nada. He intentado poner un unico alert con textos prueba para ver si funciona, y si, los muestra pero no hace nada; inclusive el "alert("Error");" del codigo que investigue no se muestra.
Nota: Esto no busco darle un tiempo y que se refresque, solo que con dar el click, cambie el div de contenido.

¿Qué esta mal?, ¿Hay otra forma de hacerlo? o mas bien ¿Cómo podría lograr lo que busco?

Agradezco de antemano sus respuestas y aportes.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes

1. Necesitas un identificador (ID) para cada categoría, luego tienes que enviar este ID a categoriaTal.php, para que este php retorne el contenido de la categoría seleccionada
2. La categoría deberia quedar de esta manera

```
<div class="elemento" onclick="cargaCategoriaTal(ID)">
    <p>Categoria Tal</p>
</div>
```

IMPORTANTE: cargaCategoriaTal(ID) donde dice ID debe ir una ID real, no la palabra id

3. Javascript

Tú tienes $(document).ready, esto es para que una función se ejecute inmediatamente despues de cargar la página por primera vez, esto NO lo necesitas. Tampoco necesitas el setInterval. Lo que si necesitas es pasar la ID al php, puedes ocupar GET (usando query string) como a continuación

```
function cargaCategoriaTal(id){
  $("#cont-princi").load("categoriaTal.php?categoria=" + id)
    .error(function() { alert("Error"); });
}
```

4. Luego en el php obtienes el id de la categoria

```
$categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
```

Y con él harás tu consulta SQL para traer el contenido correspondiente a la categría.

Comment: Ok, la pondre en mi codigo y le aviso si funciona, le agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Una vez que obtenga en "$categoria" y procese mi peticion a mi base de datos. ¿A donde retorno la informacion? Ya he puesto todo asi como me lo comentas y al pulsar para detonar el metodo, no ocurre nada.

Comment: He puesto un alert para verificar que el método "cargaCategoriaTal(id)" se haya ejecutado, y si, se ha ejecutado, pero lo demás para cargar el otro archivo php no, ni siquiera el alert con Error se muestra.

Comment: En el php usted seguramente deberá hacer una consulta a su base de datos para traer el contenido de la categoría seleccionada. Luego recorrerá con un while o un for esos datos e irá generando un HTML, que es lo típico. Mas allá de eso, como no conozco su base de datos ni sé que es lo que quiere mostrar exactamente no puedo responder

Comment: Okey mire, he hecho un test, en el categoriaTal.php solo puse Unas etiquetas de ejemplo, con el fin de que probara que con el simple hecho de presionar el botón, el div se refrescara.

Comment: Y funciona el test?

Comment: No, no actualiza el div. Se queda como siempre. En el otro categoriaTal.php (Siguiendo la misma estructura) no la cambia, sigue el mismo que se cargo en un inicio.

Comment: ¿y en el PHP ya pones un `echo $resultado;` una vez ya has montado la salida en HTML?  (suponiendo que $resultado es dicha salida) ... si es así entonces ponle un `die();` después, no se de el caso que luego haga otras cosas impidiendo su correcto retorno por lo que sea. Revisa tambien la consola a ver si ves errores durante la acción (pulsa F12 en tu navegador) y de paso el archivo de errores del servidor web que ejecuta tu PHP.

Comment: @JuanIsasi aunque revisando tu código veo que no montas una salida, la vas sacando conforme se lee el archivo, bueno, eso debería funcionar también supongo.

Comment: Se ha logrado!, gracias a esta parte y a la implementacion de JQuery con Ajax, lo he logrado. Abajo pongo el codigo, pero marco a esta como la respuesta

Comment: Gracias por orientarme y abrir mi panorama.

Answer (score 0):

Agregue esto:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function cstegoriaTal() {
                alert("Test");
                       $("#cont-princi").load('categoriaTal.php');
            }
</script>
```

Y ha funcionado.